# IMap list names and quoting with Exchange Server

Tags: python, email, exchange-server, imap

I have a simple python program to index emails on an Exchange server, and find that the list names that it returns are not all the same format. It seems that any names with any special characters (notably blanks) are double-quoted, and others are not.

```
(\Marked \HasNoChildren) "/" "Mail/_DE Courses/_cs435-ADL"
(\Marked \HasNoChildren) "/"  Mail/_etc
```

Last time I ran this program several years ago it did not have this issue. All other examples that I have seen show every name string quoted. Is this something non-standard, and well known? (I just made a regex to correct for this.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the name contains special characters, the server has to quote. If the name is plain the server may quote or not, its choice. I can easily believe that the version you used three years ago made a different choice than the one deployed today.

Answer (score 0):

In an IMAP request or response, it is possible to represent items as strings (the quoted kind) or atoms (no quotes). Using an atom format (unquoted string) is often sufficient. However, when a space is present, opting for an unquoted string would cause the string to be interpreted as two separate strings (the part before the space, and that after it). Since client and server usually know to expect a predefined number of space-delimited items in a response, doing this would result in a parse error.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. In my example all strings used to be quoted from the Exchange server, now only those requiring it are - it was the changed behavior that surprised me.

Comment: You'll find plenty of changes in behaviour, as well as non-conformance to IMAP4rev1 - especially in Microsoft technologies. To be safe you should try to cater for any acceptable format - i.e. your IMAP parser should parse a single item as a single string regardless of whether it is quoted or not.

Comment: This answer is remarkably wrong. First, it's irrelevant, since mailbox names use 'astring', not 'string'. Astrings can indeed be unquoted provided that they don't contain special characters. Second, it's factually wrong. Literals are not unquoted strings in the usual sense, but rather counted strings. The literal form of Mail/_etc would be the 14-byte sequence {9} CR LF Mail/_etc.

Comment: You are correct - for some reason I confused literals with atoms - a very silly mistake.

Comment: I have amended the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. Now the answer is correct — until someone ventures beyond the narrow realm of ASCII. Nonascii strings ("Düsseldorf", "nתֵּל־אָבִיב") need either literals or the RFC6855 extension.

Comment: Yes, but that goes beyond the scope of the question which deals with having spaces in the folder name.